# Use IEnumerable variables in asp.net razor foreach loops

Tags: c#

I'm declaring my variable with this code

```
IEnumerable<object> Update_Select_Result= null;
```

and assigning with this

```
Update_Select_Result = DB.Query(CMD_Select, Request["UpdateID"]);
```

but how can I use this variable in foreach?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to iterate on IEnumerable<object> instead of List<specificType>?  In addition, where is the Razor part of the question?

Comment: foreach (object x in Updrate_Select_Result) { ... } but don't use object

Comment: @DavidL I want assign null to "Update_Select_Result" because I'm using this variable to all part of the program so this variable must declare at the top of the codes and sometime assign assign with select sql query . I'm using this codes but , If you have better solution help me please .

Comment: @Exceptyon Thank you . I find what is the problem with your help . THANKS ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, a type OTHER than object should be used if at all possible.  Build a specific class that mirrors your return output and wrap it in a List.

```
public class ReturnType
{
    public int UpdateId { get; set; }
    public string WhateverString { get; set; }  
}


List<ReturnType> Update_Select_Result = null;
Update_Select_Result = DB.Query(CMD_Select, Request["UpdateID"]);
```

Note, you will probably have to modify your data access.  another option is to construct a new object from your return from the database.

At the top of your razor view, assign Model your new type

```
@model List<ReturnType>
```

Now that you have your model assigned, you can access it directly with "Model".  Within your razor syntax, iterate over the collection and perform whatever magic you need to.

```
@foreach (var x in Model)
{
    // do whatever you need with each member of Model (List<ReturnType>), 
    // represented by x

}
```